# System recognizes my USB 3.0 port as USB 2.0 port

Tags: usb, kernel

I have a laptop Thinkpad T520 with the dockstation Lenovo 4338-35 which has one USB 3.0 port (it's blue, marked with `SS`). However, my Linux Mint 17.2 (based on Ubuntu 14.04) does not recognize it.

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 2, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 3, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 4, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 5, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_wdm, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 6, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ncm, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 7, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ncm, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 8, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_wdm, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 9, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 10, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Chip/SmartCard, Driver=, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 3, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/7p, 480M
            |__ Port 5: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ch341, 12M
            |__ Port 6: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

If I plug some device into USB 3.0 port, it appears under `Port 5: Dev 5, If0, Class=Hub, Drive=hub/7p, 480M`:

```
$ lsusb -t
....
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
        ....
        |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/7p, 480M
            |__ Port 5: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ch341, 12M
            |__ Port 6: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
here-->     |__ Port 7: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

Device plugged into this port works normally, just like in any other (USB 2.0) port.

I've seen it other outputs people posted that USB 3.0 devices should appear with speed `5000M`, but I have `480M` only.

Some other outputs:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 17ef:1003 Lenovo Integrated Smart Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bdb:1911 Ericsson Business Mobile Networks BV 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f2:b217 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Lenovo Integrated Camera (0.3MP)
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0458:003a KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) NetScroll+ Mini Traveler / Genius NetScroll 120
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 17ef:100a Lenovo ThinkPad Mini Dock Plus Series 3
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [Quadro NVS 4200M] (rev ff)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
0d:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 08)
```

Kernel version is 3.16:

```
$ uname -r
3.16.0-38-generic
```

Could anyone give some clue how to make it recognize as USB 3.0, please? Thanks.

Comment: Have you plugged in a USB 3.0 device? Cheers, Al

Comment: I have, but the presence of usb 3.0 hub does not depend on whether something is plugged into. Anyway, the question has been answered here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305364/system-recognizes-my-usb-3-0-port-as-usb-2-0-port , the thing is: docking station does not have USB 3.0 controller, it uses the laptop's controller. Mine doesn't have one. I was naive enough to believe that the docking station has its own one.

Comment: So, just for clarification, your laptop has no USB 3.0 (blue) ports, but the docking station does have USB 3.0 ports? Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema, yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the driver is listed as `ehci`.  You might need to enable `xhci` support in your BIOS to get USB 3 working.